# Openshift 3.11: controller-manager crashloopbackoff - unable to retrieve the complete list of server APIs: servicecatalog.k8s.io/v1beta

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-3

I have a issue with my controller-manager and hours of debugging been not successful.

Log:
"controller_manager.go:232] error running controllers: failed to get api versions from server: failed to get supported resources from server: unable to retrieve the complete list of server APIs: servicecatalog.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently unable to handle the request"

But if run "kubectl api-versions" then servicecatalog.k8s.io/v1beta1 is listed.

Anyone here who can help me? :/

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution to this was to delete the "apiserver" pods in the daemon set with the same name. The controller-manager pods access these apiserver pods. Afterwards I deleted the "controller-manager" pods, so the daemonset would recreate them.

The deletion of the apiserver pods was necessary due to an update to the OpenShift internal certificates. That way, the apiserver pods used the updated certs and both daemonsets worked again.